How can I return a derived class instance from a base class function
Let's say I have two classes. base and derived_from_base. base will contain a lot of functions that will control certain aspects of base and the derived classes will use. However, I would like to make it so I can chain calls to these functions.
class data_class {};

class base {
public:
  base* add_data(data_class* data) {
    m_Data = data;
    return this;
  }

private:
  data_class* m_Data;
};

class derived_from_base : public base {
  void custom_function() {}
};

int main() {
  data_class* someData = new data_class();

  // "myClass" has none of the data after this return
  derived_from_base* myClass = derived_from_base().add_data(someData);

  derived_from_base* myOtherClass = derived_from_base();
  // The data is available in this class now.
  myOtherClass.add_data(someData);
}

I have tried passing the derived classes this pointer to the base class but it has yielded the same results.

Why do you expect "this variable" to have any data? You're passing a copy of it to the base class, which then stores another copy in a member variable? Also, whatever you expect myClass to be, it's a dangling pointer because the temporary object gets removed. In fact, from the looks of it, the compiler should even warn you because you're assigning a base-class pointer to a derived-class pointer, which is not safe.

In my actual code I pass a pointer to the function add_data. However, when I separate the add_data call the data is available in myClass. I was hoping to be able to chain these calls together. I will edit my question to include these two things.

You could have saved yourself some typing by naming your class derived instead of derived_from_base (since there is no ambiguity with the base class appropriately named base).

It looks like you have two issues: 1) casting the pointer returned by add_data to a derived_from_base pointer and 2) having a dangling pointer to a temporary object. Which of these did you intend to ask about? The former is a compile-time error, so it would need to be addressed before the latter. (Unless you were to change your code to base* myClass = base().add_data(someData); which likely exhibits the same "has none of the data after this return" without the need for a derived class. Having two of these lines with different data is even more likely to demonstrate the dangling pointer.)

In the future please write [mcve]s.  You provided code that doesn't compile and then talked about runtime errors in it.

One way things like this are sometimes accomplished is via the CRTP-idiom.
In your case this would look something like this:
class Base {
private:
  // ...
public:
  Base* add_data(data_class* data) {
    // implementation ...
  }
};

template <typename T>
class BaseCRTP : public Base {
public:
  T* add_data(class_data* data) {
    return static_cast<T*>(Base::add_data(data));
  }
};

class Derived : public BaseCRTP<Derived> {
public:
  void custom_function() {}
};

int main() {
  Derived derived;
  derived.add_data(new class_data())->custom_function();
}

This is not the best style in several points. For one, it would be better to return a reference, not a pointer. So *this, not this.
Anyway, by introducing an intermediate base class template you offload the code-reuse to a template and have to write a wrapper only once.

C++23's "deducing this" feature should be able to simplify this code so BaseCRTP is not needed anymore.

@RemyLebeau Yes, you're right. I'd edit it into the answer, but OP is tagged C++20.

oh, I didn't notice that, thanks
